# Installing React Native Map. AIRMap not found in UIManager

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

It might have been a few people asking this question, I have been looking all over Github, but can't find a solution that works for installing React Native Maps...

> Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "AIRMap" was not found in
>   the UIManager.
>
> This error is located at:
>       in AIRMap (at MapView.js:760)
>       in MapView (at Home.js:118)

```
  "react-native": "^0.57.0-rc.4",
  "react-native-maps": "^0.21.0",
```

I have tried:

```
rm -rf ios android node_modules
npm install
react-native upgrade
react-native link

libAirMaps.a is added in Build Phases
AirGoogleMaps and AirMaps is added to Libraries
```

Followed this guide to add Maps SDK for iOS manually without CocoaPods: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start

Added `@import GoogleMaps;` and `[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"_YOUR_API_KEY_"];` to `AppDelegate.m`

Still getting the same error...

I have not added this to package.json, as I am unsure what path it is asking for? I found this at https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

```
{
  "name": "your-app",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/react-native-maps/enable-google-maps REPLACE_ME_RELATIVE_PATH_TO_GOOGLE_MAPS_INSTALL"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the Google Map doc and install the SDK manually, you may have add those three frameworks to your project, just right click the framework in Xcode and then **Show in Finder**, you can find the framework file in finder

[image]

[image]

and in my case , the `REPLACE_ME_RELATIVE_PATH_TO_GOOGLE_MAPS_INSTALL` refers to my ios directory, the related path is `./ios`, just add this to the `package.json` file and run 
    `npm install`

```js
{
  "name": "your-app",
  "scripts": {
     "postinstall": "./node_modules/react-native-maps/enable-google-maps ./ios"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer may no longer be relevant for RN >0.60. Be sure to follow the instructions for installation here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md which includes the appdelegate.m changes and the podfile changes. Then also add the following line to the top of your podfile.

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'